# ALSA and PulseAudio starting without being invoked by init system?

Tags: pulseaudio, alsa, init

Forgive me if this is a noob question, however, I just installed Artix with OpenRC, and while following the [guide on setting up ALSA with OpenRC from the gentoo wiki](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/ALSA#OpenRC), I was told to add the `alsasound` service to OpenRC using:

`rc-update add alsasound boot`

I was about to do this, until I realized that Pulseaudio and ALSA are actually both already running, despite me never explicitly running them nor adding them as services to OpenRC. Maybe I am confused and incorrect here, but shouldn't those programs not start unless I tell the init system (`OpenRC`) to start them? Is there a way that I can find out what is invoking ALSA and Pulseaudio to start, if it's not my init system?

Apologies if I am confused about the way these sound applications and init systems operate, as this is my first time tinkering with them and trying to manually set them up.

Comment: ALSA kernel modules will probably get autoloaded if your sound chip is on a bus that is autodetectable, such as PCI and PCIe. Pulseaudio is normally started by the user's session when someone logs in locally on the console. What exactly are you seeing that leads you to make the determination that "Pulseaudio and ALSA are actually both already running"?

Comment: When I log in I use `pactl list` and `aplay -l` commands, both of which would return an error if pulseaudio or alsa respectively wouldn't be running. I was just confused because I never explicitly started either program after logging in nor did I add them as OpenRC services, so I was wondering what was behind launching them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`aplay -l` only needs the kernel modules, which can be autoloaded by the kernel if your sound card/chip is PCI-based or otherwise autodetectable by the kernel (or listed in device tree information if you have an ARM system, I guess?).

But the autoloading may not take care of restoring your sound mixer settings, so everything will be using "factory default" volume settings, which may be quite low to protect the hearing of the users of headphones from accidental auditory assault.

On `systemd`-based systems (which I'm more familiar with) `pulseaudio` is started either directly as a user service, or via socket activation using `pulseaudio.socket` systemd unit.

On a system using OpenRC, PulseAudio might be started by the GUI session start-up scripts: it doesn't necessarily have to run as root.

But PulseAudio also has an *autospawning mechanism*: if you start any PulseAudio client while the server is not running, the client will attempt to start the server automatically, unless `/etc/pulse/client.conf` or `~/.config/pulse/client.conf` includes the setting `autospawn = no`.